# Power BI Desktop with the Azure Data Lake Store?

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-lake

I am connecting the Power BI to Azure Data Lake store with multiple files representing multiple tables.

1)
*update* It is currently loading the data into the Power BI file.*update*
But, can I have live connection from Power BI Desktop with the Azure Data Lake Store?

2) 
Can I load multiple files to represent Dimensions and Fact tables.

Answer (score 1):

From desktop you can access the Azure Data Lake Store data source - just make sure you're using a recent version of Power BI Desktop [Data Lake Store - Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-power-bi).

You can join multiple queries together in Power BI desktop

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for PowerBI does not list Azure Data Lake Store as a source that can be connected live as of May 2018: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data#live-connections-and-directquery-to-on-premises-data-sources.

Alternatively, you could try using Azure Stream Analytics to create a job that can copy data, and connect to the live stream, but that process might need to be manually triggered and requires data movement, which might not be ideal for your scenario. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-stream-analytics

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get data from Azure Data Lake Store from Power BI desktop application:

[image]

Also, you can join multiple queries from different tables into PBI desktop app.